# Tensorflow C API placeholder / input variable setting

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use the TensorFlow C-API to run a implementation of LeNet that has been saved from a Keras/TF model, but I am having consistent problems with setting the input. Relevant piece of code is:

```
  // Load the image with openCV
  CvMat * img = cvLoadImageM(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );

  // Create an Tensor from the image
  int64_t dims4[]={1,1,28,28};
  TF_Tensor * imgTensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT,dims4,4,img,28*28*sizeof(float),NULL,NULL);


  TF_Operation* init_op2 = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "conv2d_1_input");
  TF_Operation* targets[] = {init_op2};

  // Build up the inputs
  TF_Output inp = {
          init_op2,
          0
  };
  TF_Output * inputs[] = {&inp};
  TF_Tensor * input_values[] = {imgTensor};

  printf("\nBefore\n");
  TF_SessionRun(session, NULL,
                &inp, inputvalues, 1,  // inputs
               NULL, NULL, 0,  // outputs
                &init_op2, 1,    // targets
                NULL,
                status);
  printf("After\n");
  printf("Status %d %s\n", TF_GetCode(status), TF_Message(status));
```

However, anyway I try to build up the input tensor, I get the error status and message:

```
Status 3 You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,1,28,28]
     [[Node: conv2d_1_input = Placeholder[_output_shapes=[[?,1,28,28]], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1,28,28], _device=...]()]]
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure init_op2 is not nullptr? Otherwise the code as is written should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to [`TF_SessionRun`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1247), you're also providing the `conv2d_1_input` operation as a "target". The error message can be improved, but it's basically complaining that you're asking the session to execute a placeholder operation, which it can't - which isn't possible (see the note in the documentation for [`tf.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder))

Shouldn't you be asking for a different `target` or `output` tensor from the call to `TF_SessionRun` with something like:

```
TF_Output out = { TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "<name_of_output_tensor>"), 0 };

TF_Tensor* outputvalues = NULL;
TF_SessionRun(session, NULL,
              &inp, inputvalues, 1,  // inputs
              &out, &outputvalues, 1,  // outputs
              NULL, 0,  // targets
              NULL, status);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem I didn't see!